# Copying file from one location to other

Tags: android, progressdialog

I am copying file from one location to another location in sdcard.
now at the time when copy starts i use a progress Dialog,but how can i know that my file has been transferred to close the progress dialog.I am not able to close progress Bar because I don't know how to get message of transfer complete.
Please help me Out..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this very recent post and Vladimir's answer, I think a Service may be overkill (depending on your exact situation). AsyncTask would probably be the way to go.

[Want to display AlertDialog in onCreate of Activity - android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5755980/want-to-display-alertdialog-in-oncreate-of-activity-android)

Answer (score 0):

Start a service that will copy the file to the sd card.  I recommend IntentService because it automatically creates a separate thread for you. Once the file is done being copied send a Broadcast from your service with your intent. Then back in your activity class create a Broadcast Receiver that will handle the broadcast.  Don't forget to include your service in the androidmanifest.xml file. Here is some code:

This code will go at the end of your service

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.setAction("com.me.custom.intent.filecopied.success");
sendBroadcast(i);
```

If the file failed to copy do this

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.setAction("com.me.custom.intent.filecopied.fail");
sendBroadcast(i);
```

Then back in your main activity class you must receive the intent:

```
MyBroadcastReceiver intentReceiver = new MyBroadcastReceiver ();

    public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
            pdialog.dismiss();//dismiss your dialog
            if (arg1.getAction().toString().equals("com.me.custom.intent.filecopied.success")) {
                //Do whatever on file being copied successfully
            } else if (arg1.getAction().toString().equals("com.me.custom.intent.filecopied.fail"L)) {
                //Do whatever on file not being copied successfully
            }
        }

    }
```

Also in your activity you must register/unregister the broadcast

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Mark time user logged out
    unregisterReceiver(intentReceiver );
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Add login check
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("com.me.custom.intent.filecopied.success");
    filter.addAction("com.me.custom.intent.filecopied.fail");
    registerReceiver(intentReceiver , filter);
    super.onResume();
}
```