# Want to display AlertDialog in onCreate of Activity - android

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, showdialog, oncreate

In my activity, I call a MyDialog (custom dialog) in onCreate() and handle its DismissListener in Activity to find if its cancelled or not. If its cancelled, I finish the activity, else load the activty. During this loading time, I want to show a Alert/Progress dialog to let the user know that its loading, please wait. But am not able to see the dialog. This is how I have coded :

```
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ld = new AgreeDialog(this);
    ld.setOnDismissListener(new OnDismissListener() {
@Override
public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
           if (ld.isCancelled)
    MyActivity.this.finish();
       else {
    //ProgressDialog pd = CreateLoadingDialog();
    //pd.show();
    //Log.i(TAG, "Before Load Is PD showing - " + pd.isShowing());  // Shows true
          /*
    AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(StartUltimate.this);
    adb.setTitle("Loading...");
    adb.setCancelable(false);
    AlertDialog ad = adb.create();
    ad.show();
    */  
    MyActivity.this.showDialog(0);
    LoadAfteAgree();  // This takes time sonetimes, so want a dialog while this is working 
    MyActivity.this.removeDialog(0);

    //ad.dismiss();
                // pd.dismiss();
    //Log.i(TAG, "After Load Is PD showing - " + ad.isShowing());    // Shows false
     }
}           
    });

@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch(id) {
    case 0:
        loadingDlg = new ProgressDialog(this);
        loadingDlg.setMessage("Loading...");
        loadingDlg.setCancelable(false);
        loadingDlg.setIcon(R.drawable.icon);
        return loadingDlg;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Why am I not able to see any dialog in any way ? I tried calling them in LoadAfterAgree() also,  but there also no success, same results.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: If you can't see any dialog, try showing it in the 'onStart()'-method instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you're performing your long operations in UI thread. Move them to the AsyncTask's doInBackground method. See the example [here](http://it-projects.spb.ru/?p=150&lang=en).

Comment: To a add a little bit to this... the screen will not start drawing anything until after the onCreate() method has returned (and I believe after onStart() and onResume() as well). So you're telling the system to show it, do some work and then hide it before any layout and draw functions are even called by the framework. In short, do what Vladimir says.

Answer (score 3):

To stop your dialog causing any memory leaks, ensure the following is included in your activity;

```
AlertDialog _alert;

  @Override
  public void onPause() {
      super.onPause();

      if(_alert != null)
          _alert.dismiss();
  }
```

Comment: Thanks. Don't know how hwlpful the above code will be, but have added in my Activity class to avoid any sort of window leakage errors.